# Way to get Gradle Jacoco to Output Coverage to Console?

Tags: java, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

In python, using `Coverage.py` we are able to get line information about code coverage on the command line using `coverage report --show-missing`. This showed what lines of each file weren't being covered.

Using gradle plugins, the best output I can get is:

```
- Class Coverage: 10% 
- Method Coverage: 3.2% 
- Branch Coverage: 100% 
- Line Coverage: 1.2% 
- Instruction Coverage: 1.1% 
- Complexity Coverage: 3.2%
```

However as this does not give line information, you may as well just look at html output.

My `test.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'com.github.ksoichiro.console.reporter' version '0.6.2'
    id 'org.barfuin.gradle.jacocolog' version '1.2.4'
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('lib/json.jar')
    implementation files('lib/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.0-M1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/jsonassert-1.2.3.jar')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
    ignoreFailures = true
}
test.outputs.upToDateWhen {false}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

group 'unsw.blackout'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ['src']
sourceSets.test.java.excludes = ['degree/*']
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
sourceSets.main.java.excludes = ['degree/*']
```

Is there an equivalence for gradle?